# Arithmetic in MySQL for count of actions in a minute

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have this table in MySQL:

```
 id  |           Action             |         DateTime           |   Time(ms)  
-----+------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------
  1  | Player1_rightKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:17.795000 |   7322
  2  | Player1_shootKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:17.971000 |   7498
  3  | Player1_rightKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.035000 |   7562
  4  | Player2_leftKeyPress_Start   | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.126000 |   7653
  5  | Player1_shootKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.214000 |   7741
  6  | Player1_rightKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.305000 |   7832
  7  | Player2_leftKeyPress_Start   | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.369000 |   7896
  8  | Player1_shootKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.374000 |   7901
  9  | Player1_rightKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.467000 |   7994
 10  | Player1_shootKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.580000 |   8107
 11  | Player1_rightKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.676000 |   8203
 12  | Player1_shootKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.812000 |   8339
 13  | Player1_rightKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:18.899000 |   8426
 14  | Player1_shootKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:19.050000 |   8577
 15  | Player1_rightKeyPress_Start  | 2014-10-01 18:51:19.123000 |   8650
```

This is just a part of the table in the database. What I want to do is to count the number of times `Player1_rightKeyPress_Start`, `Player1_shootKeyPress_Start` and `Player2_leftKeyPress_Start` occurred in every 10,000second. The time runs up to 600,000 miliseconds. I did not bother to include all of it because it is really large.

Comment: is there any way you could provide an SQL dump for your data? It is difficult to understand when you have displayed it in text on your page :)

Comment: can you show what your desired output would look like? given your provided data, what would your end result look like?

Comment: 10,000 seconds is a long time -- almost 3 hours.  I don't really understand your question.

Comment: oh, I meant to type 10,000 milliseconds  or 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You probably could do something along these lines: convert to seconds, divide by 10 to get the 10 second intervals, and then apply the group by:

```
SELECT Action, FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateTime)/10)), COUNT(*)
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY Action, FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateTime)/10)
```

Check the mysql docs for the time functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but the following sql should count the occurrence of `Player1_rightKeyPress_Start` in the entire table (swap [TABLENAME]):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE Action = 'Player1_rightKeyPress_Start';
```

Paste the result of `desc [TABLENAME]` and `SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME] LIMIT 10;` would help. And add your desired result as @Sean said should also help.